# Adding multiple word tables into word using interop

Tags: c#, office-interop, word-automation

I'm trying to insert multiple tables into a word document using c#, but when I add another block of code to add a table in I am getting an error and the second table is not being inserted. How do I move the range down to the bottom of the page and then add another table? I tried creating a new range using the end of doc reference but this doesn't seem to work, can anyone give me some help?

```
    Word._Application objApp;
    Word._Document objDoc;
    try
    {

        object objMiss = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
        object objEndOfDocFlag = "\\endofdoc"; /* \endofdoc is a predefined bookmark */

        //Start Word and create a new document.
        objApp = new Word.Application();
        objApp.Visible = true;
        objDoc = objApp.Documents.Add(ref objMiss, ref objMiss,
            ref objMiss, ref objMiss);

        //Insert a paragraph at the end of the document.
        Word.Paragraph objPara2; //define paragraph object
        object oRng = objDoc.Bookmarks.get_Item(ref objEndOfDocFlag).Range; //go to end of the page
        objPara2 = objDoc.Content.Paragraphs.Add(ref oRng); //add paragraph at end of document
        objPara2.Range.Text = "Test Table Caption"; //add some text in paragraph
        objPara2.Format.SpaceAfter = 10; //defind some style
        objPara2.Range.InsertParagraphAfter(); //insert paragraph

        //Insert a table
        Word.Table objTab1; //create table object
        Word.Range objWordRng = objDoc.Bookmarks.get_Item(ref objEndOfDocFlag).Range; //go to end of document
        objTab1 = objDoc.Tables.Add(objWordRng, 9, 2, ref objMiss, ref objMiss); //add table object in word document
        objTab1.Range.ParagraphFormat.SpaceAfter = 6;
        objTab1.Range.Borders[Word.WdBorderType.wdBorderBottom].LineStyle = Word.WdLineStyle.wdLineStyleThickThinLargeGap;
        objTab1.Range.Borders[Word.WdBorderType.wdBorderHorizontal].LineStyle = Word.WdLineStyle.wdLineStyleDouble;
        objTab1.Range.Borders[Word.WdBorderType.wdBorderTop].LineStyle = Word.WdLineStyle.wdLineStyleDouble;
        objTab1.Range.Borders[Word.WdBorderType.wdBorderLeft].LineStyle = Word.WdLineStyle.wdLineStyleDouble;
        objTab1.Range.Borders[Word.WdBorderType.wdBorderRight].LineStyle = Word.WdLineStyle.wdLineStyleDouble;
        objTab1.Columns.Borders[Word.WdBorderType.wdBorderVertical].LineStyle = Word.WdLineStyle.wdLineStyleDouble; 


        objTab1.Columns[1].Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = Word.WdColor.wdColorGray20;
        objTab1.Columns[1].Width = objApp.CentimetersToPoints(3.63f);
        objTab1.Columns[2].Width = objApp.CentimetersToPoints(13.11f);



        int iRow, iCols;

        string[] col = new string[9];
        col[0] = "Row1";
        col[1] = "row2";
        col[2] = "Row3";
        col[3] = "row4";
        col[4] = "row5";
        col[5] = "row6";
        col[6] = "row7";
        col[7] = "row8";
        col[8] = "tow9";

        for (iRow = 1; iRow <= 9; iRow++)
        {
            objTab1.Rows[iRow].Range.Font.Bold = 1;
            for (int i = 0; i <= col.Length; i++)
            {

                string s = col[i];

                objTab1.Rows[iRow++].Range.Text = s;
                objTab1.Rows[iRow].Range.Font.Bold = 1;

            }

        }

        objApp.Selection.TypeParagraph();


            //Insert a paragraph at the end of the document.
            Word.Paragraph objPara3; //define paragraph object
            object oRng2 = objDoc.Bookmarks.get_Item(ref objEndOfDocFlag).Range; //go to end of the page
            objPara3 = objDoc.Content.Paragraphs.Add(ref oRng2); //add paragraph at end of document
            objPara3.Range.Text = "hello"; //add some text in paragraph
            objPara3.Format.SpaceAfter = 10; //defind some style
            objPara3.Range.InsertParagraphAfter(); //insert paragraph

            //Insert a 2 x 2 table, (table with 2 row and 2 column)
            Word.Table objTab2; //create table object
            Word.Range objWordRng2 = objDoc.Bookmarks.get_Item(ref objEndOfDocFlag).Range; //go to end of document
            objTab2 = objDoc.Tables.Add(objWordRng2, 9, 2, ref objMiss, ref objMiss); //add table object in word document
            objTab2.Range.ParagraphFormat.SpaceAfter = 6;
            object stylename2 = "Table Grid";
```

I get the following exception "the requested member of the collection does not exist"

Comment: You can probably get rid of all of those "ref" and "Missing" if you use a modern version of C#...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without fully following how you want the layout to appear. There are a couple of issues with the posted code. First in the `for` loops where you are adding the text to the first table, I am not sure what you are doing with the following lines:

```
objTab1.Rows[iRow++].Range.Text = s;
objTab1.Rows[iRow].Range.Font.Bold = 1;
```

The `iRow++` increment in the first line is going to throw off where the row is in the table. I am guessing you may want:

```
objTab1.Rows[iRow].Range.Font.Bold = 1;
objTab1.Rows[iRow].Range.Text = s;
iRow++;
```

The other issue is how the code is getting the last paragraph like below:

```
object oRng2 = objDoc.Bookmarks.get_Item(ref objEndOfDocFlag).Range;
objPara3 = objDoc.Content.Paragraphs.Add(ref oRng);
```

The `oRng2` range is the end of doc range however, the next line uses `oRng` which is the top of the document. Changing the add paragraphs to the proper range should fix this.

```
objPara3 = objDoc.Content.Paragraphs.Add(ref oRng2);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I appreciate your answer, this doesn't actually fix my problem as i am still getting the same error i had before. Also moving the Irow++ causes an out of bound error on the array, my for loop works exactly as i wanted it too so i don't want to change it.

Comment: I am confused… you mean the `for` loops as you have them posted now… WORK? I get a member not part of collection error which makes sense because you are going out of bounds of the table.

Comment: When `iRow` gets to 9, the line: `objTab1.Rows[iRow++].Range.Text = s;` will increment `iRow` to 10. When you get to the next line `objTab1.Rows[iRow].Range.Font.Bold = 1;`… this will be out of range because `objTab1` only has 9 rows.

Comment: I apologize, you are correct. I change the [IRow++] sections as you said but also realised i needed to change 

      for (iRow = 1; iRow < 9; iRow++)
                {
                    objTab1.Rows[iRow].Range.Font.Bold = 1;
                    for (int i = 0; i < col.Length; i++)
                    {

Which I didn't do until you explained further thank you.

Comment: Where is this field instantiated, "objEndOfDocFlag"?