# C# Microsoft words in visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ms-word

I need to make a dynamic number of tables in a loop. Put information in each cell and much non table information in between the tables. there is so little information out there for using c# behind word.

```
   foreach (var drug in p.Drugs)
        {
        Word.Range tableLocation =  this.Application.ActiveDocument.Range(0, 0);
        this.Application.ActiveDocument.Tables.Add(tableLocation, 5, 1);
   //insert the information
   //bunch of other stuff
        }
```

Comment: Huh, you just google "C# Word Interop <question>", there is tonnes of info. Searching for 'add table' I get the official documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w1702h4a.aspx and How to: Programmatically Add Text and Formatting to Cells in Word Tables

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tkf9d64e.aspx

Comment: thanks for that, but i have not seen one that was done using a loop to add multiple tables. I have tried many of the things i have found most just add rows to the original table rather than being its own new table or just overwrite the original table over and over.

Comment: Investigate this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42496987/adding-multiple-word-tables-into-word-using-interop - to add multiple tables put the code in a loop as you've dome

Comment: Put the code in the Duplicates Answer into your codes `foreach`